# blur event is not working in select2js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I used `select2` js(version 4) for my current project, and i need to perform operation on `blur` event of `select2 element`. My code is as below.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="">Select all report Number(s)</label>
   <select class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control" id="id_label_multiple" name="list" multiple="multiple">
      <option value=""></option>
         @foreach($reports as $item)
            <option value="{{$item->report_no}}">{{$item->report_no}}</option>
         @endforeach
   </select>
 </div>
```

javascript code

```
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
     placeholder: 'Select Seller'                       
});
$("#id_label_multiple").on('blur', function () {
     alert('Call Blur Evenet');
});
```

other events are working perfect such as `change`. but something went wrong with blur event.

Comment: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3152

Answer (score 0):

The select2 v4 docs don't list `blur` as a supported event, but `select2:close` is working for me.

```
$("#id_label_multiple").on('select2:close', function () {
    alert('Call Close Event');
});
```

ref: https://select2.github.io/options.html#events

Comment: Interesting, but this not solve the thing I need, this works like a "change" event. It is $("#id_label_multiple").change(function () {
    alert('Call Close Event');
});
But I need an event when the select lost the focus. Because I am selecting multiple elements and I want an event when the selection has finished.

Comment: @DanielSilva did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I was not able to continue using select2 since it wasn't 508 compliant.